# drupal 8 block not working

Tags: 8, blocks

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license enter code here code here`e header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Drupal\hello_world\Plugin\MyCustomBlock;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
/*
 *  @block
 * id = "mycustomblock"
 * admin_label = @Translation("mycustomblock"), 
 */
class MyCustomBlock extends BlockBase{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
      return array('#markup' => 'test block');
  }
}
```

I just create a test block and want to place into content region from admin panel.
Above is my code, but I can't see any block in the admin panel, can anybody help, what I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) "not working" isn't a useful problem statement, please take some time to edit your question and describe what the problem is, and what steps you've taken to debug so far. Many thanks

Comment: The annotation is wrong.

Comment: I update the annotation:

/*
  *  @block(
  * id = "mycustomblock",
  * admin_label = @Translation("mycustomblock")
  * ) 
  */


but still not working

Answer (score 1):

I think your block definition must be like this :

```
 /*
  *  @block(
  * id = "mycustomblock",
  * admin_label = @Translation("mycustomblock")
  * ) 
  */
```

See : [Create a custom block](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-block)

Comment: Perhaps emphasize the differences with the original code? I initially thought the code was the same and had to look twice to spot the brackets and the comma :)

Comment: A comma is missing at this line : * id = "mycustomblock"